# How to make this Toast message work on my Wordpresss Site on a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am struggling to use toast message on my website which may be visible on the click of a button. here is the code below.

```
<html>
<head> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>


<h2>Snackbar / Toast</h2>

<button onclick="updateit()">Show Snackbar</button>

<script src="https//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script src="https//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 function updateit(){
    toastr.success('button clicked');
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Even adding event listener calling in function script did not work for me.
I am using the below library which suggested me to use external scripts and style as have been used in the code above.

https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/

I am a novice, please help me out with this. 
Also, if you can help me out figuring out how can I directly get it done on WordPress, it would be highly appreciable.

Comment: Try placing the toastr library script tag after jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This code... There are some small mistakes.. I fixed... Check this..

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>


<h2>Snackbar  Toast</h2>

<button onclick="updateit()">Show Snackbar</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script>
 function updateit(){
    toastr.success('button clicked');
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: through the code, I got to know that JQuery is used on the top of Javascript that's why my code was not running well... thank you so much for the assistance.

Comment: First mistake is,  `https//` should be `https://`. toastr is using jQuery. So we need to define jQuery before. Then only browser understand.

Comment: If my code solve your problem. Then mark the answer.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you :)